# How to manually forward-fill values to make a boolean slice?

Tags: python, pandas

That's a simple question to explain but the solution is not easy for me. I can't figure it out.

I have a dataframe with two columns as input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': [True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
        'stop': [False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]})
```

​
And I need to create a third one that will hold `True` values from the start to the stop.

PS : I made the `False` values as empty strings just for clarity, guys !

```
   start  stop ===(expected_column)==> slice
0   True                                True
1                                       True
2                                       True
3         True                          True
4                                           
5   True                                True
6         True                          True
7                                           
8                                           
9                                           
10                                          
11
```

I desperately tried below but the row with the index 6 gives `False` instead of `True`.

```
df['slice'] = (df['start'] | df.index.isin(range(df['start'].idxmax(), df['stop'].idxmax() + 1)))
```

Is there a solution, please ? Feels like we need to use `groupby` with some custom ops but I wonder if there is a differernt approach.

In case you wonder, the dataset will always have one single `True` per row.

Comment: will the first row always have a True start time?  In this case, the expected column will always be full of True.  O.w, if the first start time is False, fill the expected the column with the number of rows with starting times that are False, and then the rest True.

Comment: The dataset guarantees that the column `start` will always have the first `True` value (not necessarily in the first row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['start'].where(df['start'] | df['stop'].shift()).ffill().fillna(False)
```

or

```
df['start'].groupby(df['stop'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()).cummax()
```

or

```
df.sum(axis=1).cumsum().mod(2).eq(1) | df['stop']
```

Output:

```
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4     False
5      True
6      True
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
```

Comment: I would have done the same, you might want to provide the intermediates for clarity ;)

Comment: Also, note that if the first value is not True you will need to `fillna(False)`

Comment: Thank you, I'm sending you r *'hugs'* of gratitude!

Answer (score 0):

My take on this problem is to always assign arbitrary group numbering using cumsum and comparing them accordingly.

```
>>> df
    start   stop
0    True  False
1   False  False
2   False  False
3   False   True
4   False  False
5    True  False
6   False   True
7   False  False
8   False  False
9   False  False
10  False  False
11  False  False
>>> start_group = df.start.eq(True).cumsum()
>>> stop_group = df.stop.eq(True).cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0)
>>> df['slice'] = start_group.sub(1).eq(stop_group)
>>> df
    start   stop  slice
0    True  False   True
1   False  False   True
2   False  False   True
3   False   True   True
4   False  False  False
5    True  False   True
6   False   True   True
7   False  False  False
8   False  False  False
9   False  False  False
10  False  False  False
11  False  False  False
>>>
```

Comment: I can't upvote you my friend but your solution works 100%. Thank you.